# GTK native version of Amarok

Tags: 12.04, sound, kde, gtk

Does anybody know of a version of Amarok written in GTK ?

This is my fave music player but if I install using apt-get I have to install 200mb of KDE dependencies. I saw a Windows beta version so heres hoping, it would just be nice if I could find a GTK version.

Comment: Try with [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/it/)

Comment: @Ceppo93 Clementine is also written in Qt.

Comment: But no KDE dependencies ;)

Comment: tried this was quite different but still very good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install amarok --no-install-recommends` will download what's only necessary for Amarok to run (only 69MB <-these are the dependencies) and it will use 199MB when installed (which I guess is what you mean).

Amarok will probably never be written in GTK as it's part of KDE.

there is however [Listen](http://www.listen-project.org/) a GTK based player similar to Amarok.

> Listen is an audio player written in Python. Thanks to it, you can    easily organize your music collections.

- It supports many features such as Podcasts management, browse
  Shoutcast directory.
- It provides a direct access to lyrics, lastfm and wikipedia
  informations.
- It intuitively creates playlists for you by retrieving informations
  from lastfm and what you most frequently listen to

[image]

And let's not forget [Exaile](http://www.exaile.org/) which is also similar to Amarok but to a lesser degree, it's available in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install exaile
```

[image]